# How to give glow to linearlayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, shadow

I tried giving glow to linear layout like we give to textview :

```
 <style name="shadowstyle">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/clrab</item>
    <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/clrab</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDx">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowDy">0.0</item>
    <item name="android:shadowRadius">8</item>
</style>
```

But it isn't working for linearlayout.

I want a output like this :

[image]

How to I give this glow to this linearlayout.

I am trying cardview layout but not working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make 9 patch image for your layout .

set this 9 patch image as a background in your layout